# .htaccess how to check REQUEST_URI doesn't contain any file type

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have 2 type of routing mechanism

1. if it is a png or jpeg, redirect to a folder named assets
2. if it is not a png or jpeg, redirect to index.php

now i want to extend file types but i don't want to write them one by one, how can i check if is there any extension at the end of the url?

Current redirect(manual one);

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpe?g|bmp|png|gif|svg|webp|mp3|mp4|css|js|woff2|woff|ttf|html|map)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} frontend/assets
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NC,L,END]
```

what i've tried;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\.(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} frontend/assets
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NC,L,END]
```

Comment: What is the full URL-path of these "assets"? Your rule doesn't actually do what you say it does. It simply "does nothing" when an asset is requested - which is most certainly the intention. But why do you need to check the file extension? Is it not enough to check the file-path? Are you storing things other than known assets in this directory? It looks like this could be greatly simplified. Please include the contents of your complete `.htaccess` file (also showing rules for #2).

Comment: When I say "does nothing"... it's an exception, it prevents further processing, but it certainly doesn't "redirect" anything.

Comment: @MrWhite basicly i want to redirect all spesific urls to index.php and rest(that contains file extension like test.png, asd.js.map) content.php
but i don't want to write every extension to rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this instead:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# 1. Exception for URL requests that contain a file extension
#  - Prevents further processing
RewriteRule \.\w{2,5}$ - [END]

# 2. Rewrite everything else (including directory requests) to "index.php"
RewriteRule . index.php [END]
```

A "file extension" is deemed to be a dot followed by between 2 and 5 characters from the character from the range `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_` (underscore).

Although the above two rules could be combined into one:

```
# 1 + 2. Rewrite everything that does not have a file extension to "index.php"
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,5}$ index.php [END]
```

<sup>(Minor difference is that this rule also rewrites the root directory to `index.php` instead of relying on mod_dir.)</sup>

And if you simply want to route everything to `index.php`, except for files and directories then just use the following instead (this replaces *everything* above):

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

---

**A look at your current rules:**

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpe?g|bmp|png|gif|svg|webp|mp3|mp4|css|js|woff2|woff|ttf|html|map)$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} frontend/assets
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NC,L,END]
> ```

This is an "exception". It prevents further processing if the conditions are met. (It doesn't actually do anything to further process the URL, it just prevents the request being rewritten to the front-controller, which presumably follows.)

There's seemingly no need to check that the requested URL ends in a file extension AND the URL-path contains `frontend/assets`. If all your assets are contained in a known location then it would be arguably preferable to just exclude that known location. Although you also mention a `.php` extension in the comments, which may not fall under "assets".

There's also no need to captured the requested URL-path and rewrite the request to the same. To indicate "no substitution" just use a single *hyphen* (as I did in the rule above).

The `NC` and `L` flags are also superfluous here. `END` is a "stronger" version of `L` that prevents any further passes by the rewrite engine.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\.(.*)$
> :
> ```

This *negated* expression is kind of doing the opposite of what you are trying to achieve, except that the regex is also incorrect. This *condition* is successful when the requested URL-path does not match a URL of the form `.<anything>`. This is always going to be successful since the `REQUEST_URI` server variable *always* starts with a slash.

Comment: this solved my issue thank you.

i have one last question, if i want to do that using RewriteCond how i supposed to do?

Comment: @MustafaAkdeniz You could do it like this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,5}$` / `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` (combines 1 & 2 above) - but there's no reason to use `RewriteCond` here.